# Qt C++ QTextEdit count words while typing

Tags: c++, qt

I need to implement method in Qt C++ which counts number of words in QTextEdit while user type. Also when user type multiple spaces they shouldn't be treated as word. I know how to do this on already typed text, but I need to update total number of words all the time.
Can you help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I done it, I made combination out of some answers on this thread. As I noticed this solution is really fast and it doesn't waste resources if not needed. It checks only parts of text while you type, only if you paste text then it checks whole text. I would like someone to check this code and post some feedback. This is the code:

```
size = 0;
counter = 0;
start = 0;
end = 0;
void MainWindow::count()
{
    text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    if(text.length()-size == 1){
    if(text.length() == 1){
    if(!text.at(0).isSpace()){
        counter++;
        ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(counter));
    }}

    if(text.length()>2){
    start = text.length()-1;
    end = text.length();
    if(text.at(start-1).isSpace() && !text.at(end-1).isSpace()){
        counter++;
        ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(counter));
    }}}
    else if(text.length()-size > 1){
    counter = 0;
    if(!text.at(0).isSpace()) counter++;
        for(int i = 1; i<text.length();i++){
            if(!text.at(i).isSpace() && text.at(i-1).isSpace())
                counter++;

        }
        ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(counter));
    }
    size = text.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to connect on `void QTextEdit::textChanged () [signal]` and use something like this:

```
void onTextChanged()
{
    int wordCount = textEdit->toPlainText().split(QRegExp("(\\s|\\n|\\r)+")
                                                  , QString::SkipEmptyParts).count();
}
```

Comment: This is coolest solution so far, I only need to test it's speed when I try to process large file.

Comment: Go ahead. And write the results - I'm curious too.

Comment: This is very effective for smaller files but for big files (> 20 000 words) it consumes too much CPU and RAM is filled up.

Comment: Splitting with regexp is the slowest part for sure.

Comment: toPlainText and split? Nice memory and performance overhead. It is simple solution, but for big documents it will be a performance failure.

Comment: I see two main approaches. 1) Connect to `textChanged` signal and recalculate word count each time text changes. Rewriting faster split will help a bit, but this method will still require a lot of resources. 2) Calculate word count on text load, then - watching every user change and clarify word count, depending on the change. The second one seems much harder to me. For example you could recalculate each text block separately and store the count. A hard use case here would be removing text from several text blocks at once.

Comment: I've implemented this method as a QRunnable for a QThreadPool on a 5 second timer. It is a good enough update frequency, and works for very large documents. This avoids the problem of interrupting the main thread while typing.

Answer (score 0):

You will pretty much have to parse it yourself, splitting the string with a single splitter is not a good solution for production. Here is a simple parser I've written some time ago that does exactly this:

```
void processChar(const QChar &ch)
{
    // if char is not separator
    if (!sp[ch.unicode()]){
        if (!isWord){ // set where word begins
            wordBegin = counter;
            isWord = 1;
        }
        ++textChar;
    }
    // if char is separator
    else{
        // if there is a current word
        if (isWord){
            QString tempWord(text.mid(wordBegin, counter - wordBegin));
            tempWord = tempWord.toLower();
            // if word does not exist add with value one
            if (!words.contains(tempWord)){
                words.insert(tempWord, 1);
                ++uniqueWords;
            }
            // if word exists find its value and increment by one
            else {
                words.insert(tempWord, words.value(tempWord) + 1);
            }
            ++totalWords;
            isWord = 0;
        }
        // else skip
        ++sepChar;
    }
}
```

You call `processChar()` for each character of your text.

It is pretty fast, it uses a lookup table (char array) `sp` that includes all characters and marks those that are separators. Here is how you populate the table from a QString of all separators.

```
void indexChars()
{
    // zero everything
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 65536; ++i) sp[i] = 0;

    // set every separator index to 1
    for (int i = 0; i < separators.length(); ++i) {
        sp[separators.at(i).unicode()] = 1;
    }
}
```

The table is quite big because I wanted to be able to process 16 bit characters as well.

How fast is it - despite doing extra work, it is bout 20 times faster than the word count of MS Word, plus it actually creates a list of every unique word in the text plus the number of occurrences, stored in the QMap `words`. It tracks text characters `textChar`, separator characters `sepChar`, total and unique words.

Functionality might be a bit overkill, but you can strip it down if you don't need all the extra stuff. It will get even faster if you remove what you don't need.

You can use those snippets, and either use a timer to periodically count the words if text has changed since last count, which is the better solution than the alternative - to count on every typed character of the text field.

Comment: Are you parsing whole string from qtextedit in your example? I think this would be better if I check position of text cursor, so if cursorPosition(i) is space and cursorPosition(i+1) is not space then increase word counter by one. This way I don't have to fill up RAM when I process large files. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Alen - I guess if you want to optimize things, but you will increase complexity. On my PC, this method has about 6 million words per second. A more realistically sized text will be fast enough to leave as it is and parse the whole thing every second. You can do some load balancing also, by spreading out the parsing interval as the text gets longer. Or set it to parse once you stop typing for a few seconds. QString is implicitly shared, so you can directly use the text of the text field. It is unlikely you will ever have more than 10 MB, more like kb.

Comment: For the sake of an exercise you could track the edit changes, but it is hardly worth the time investment. After all, it is the machine that is supposed to do the hard work, so might as well leave it unless it fails to do it well enough. And in the case, the performance gain you will receive will be miniscule compared to the extra time you dedicated to achieve it. But still, a perfectly good exercise. I don't expect it to be easy though, if you have a hunch, by all means follow it, but the way I see things, the complexity is pretty high.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I thought I remembered well how QTextDocument works (I thought that `contentsChange(int position, int charsRemoved, int charsAdded)` is invoked before actual change). I was wrong or maybe behavior in new version has changed. Anyway with current version (5.0.1) I don't see how to calculate correction to word count. It looks like it is impossible. At least I don't see a way to calculate how many words has been removed.

<strike>Listen to two signals from a [QTextDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html): `contentsChange(int position, int charsRemoved, int charsAdded)` and `contentsChanged()`.
First is fired before document modification and second after. Use this information: position, charsRemoved, charsAdded; to calculate correction to total count of words.</strike>

Comment: Well, it is certainly doable. But as I pointed out in the comments of my answer, hardly necessary.

Comment: I meant that calculation of CORRECTIONS to word count looks impossible, since signal `contentsChange(int position, int charsRemoved, int charsAdded)` is fired after change was made, so fetching what was removed looks impossible (charRemoced is useless). Calculating total word count is easy (less complex then your solution), look on my second answer.

Comment: It is not like you cannot extend the stock functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculate how many words document contains from the beginning the best solution is:

```
void MainWindow::docChanged()
{
    QTextDocument *doc = qobject_cast<QTextDocument *>(sender());
    QRegExp re("\\b\\w+\\b");
    int wordCount = 0;
    QTextCursor c = doc->find(re);
    while (!c.isNull()) {
        wordCount++;
        c = doc->find(re, c);
    }
    ui->labelWordCount->setText(QString::number(wordCount));
}
```

Comment: I tried this but my application just crash when I press any button. I've never used this object casting so I can't find error, have you tested this method?

Comment: did you connect this slot with `QTextDocument::contentsChanged()`? Apparently not.

Comment: Keep in mind `QRegExpr` is much slower, I tested it against the parser from my answer, and it is about 10 times slower. That could turn out to be problematic in scenarios with long text. And I would certainly not refresh on every document change.